# Xamarin problems with UISearchBar's cancel Button in iOS 13

Tags: ios, xamarin, mobile, xamarin.ios

I'm developing a mobile application using `Xamarin.iOS` and now i've just updated the Xamarin's latest version, to have compatiblity with the new iOS 13. So far i was changing the text of the `UISearchBar` cancel button using `SetValueForKey` but now it tells me that `ivar is prohibited. This is an application bug`.

[image: Exception]

Can you help with alternatives to change the UISearchBar's cancel button text?

**EDIT**

Thanks to @Junior Jiang - MSFT it was given a quick fix [here](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/7168#issuecomment-538575111).

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport ("/usr/lib/libobjc.dylib", EntryPoint = "objc_msgSend")]
public extern static void void_objc_msgSend_IntPtr (IntPtr receiver, IntPtr selector, IntPtr arg1);

var app = UIBarButtonItem.AppearanceWhenContainedIn (typeof (UISearchBar));
using (var title = new NSString ("Cancel"))
    void_objc_msgSend_IntPtr (app.Handle, ObjCRuntime.Selector.GetHandle ("setTitle:"), title.Handle);
app.TintColor = UIColor.Red;
```

Answer (score 2):

**Unfortunately** , this method can not works now in IOS 13 .

Even though through OC menthod to do , it also can not work .

```
[searchBar setValue("Cancel", forKey: "_cancelButtonText")];
//not work in xcode
```

In Xcode , there is new way to implement it ,

```
searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;

[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setTitle:@"Cancel"];
//before IOS 9

[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UISearchBar class]]].title = @"Cancel";
//after IOS 9
```

However , in Xamarin we can not find the methods, just only can set TintColor :

```
UIBarButtonItem.AppearanceWhenContainedIn(typeof(UISearchBar)).TintColor = UIColor.White;
```

The property `Text` not found in `UIBarButtonItem` .

Then I have added it to the feature issue in GitHub Xamarin . Here is the [link](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/7785) , you can follow it up .